# Работа с камерой(android)

Tags: java, android

Открываю камеру и делаю снимок с камеры вот таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

После чего в `onActivityResult` ловлю результат

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 2) {         
                Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Сама проблема: если камера спрашивает после того как был сделан снимок "сохранить?" и чтобы не было нажато в `data` приходит `null`. Если на устройстве отключено подтверждение сохранения фотографии то всё отрабатывает корректно.

Могу предположить что android не дает `onActivityResult` получить доступ к фото после снимка и блокирует его а после того как пользователь подтвердил сохранение фотографии, `onActivityResult` уже не ловит ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сообщите приложению камеры, куда сохранить сделанное изображение:

```
File externalFilesDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File photoFile = new File(externalFilesDir, 'photo.jpg');
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

А в `onActivityResult` просто обращайтесь по известному пути.